# How to update one element of a list

Tags: list, dictionary, updates, elm

I have an `update` function that take a `postID` and a title to update my post.

I want to loop over my posts to find the post and update its value. I tried using `List.map` but I don't know where to put here. Here is what I want in pseudo code:

```
update action model =
  case action of
    UpdateTitle postID title ->
      //something like this:
      for post in model.posts :
        if post.id == postID then
          { post | title = title }

      ( model.posts , Effects.none )
```

Comment: Consider using `find` in `List.Extra` to find the post with the good id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `List.map`, passing in a mapping function that only updates the post with a matching ID.

```elm
update action model =
  case action of
    UpdateTitle postID title ->
      ( List.map (setTitleAtID title postID) model.posts , Effects.none )

setTitleAtID title postID post =
  if post.id == postID then
    { post | title = title }
  else
    post
```